# Kubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet: Why do GTK apps look ugly?

Tags: kubuntu, themes, kde, gtk

I'm running Kubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet Alpha 2. I am a KDE fan and love Plasma 5. However, I have this problem where GTK apps look like crap. Screenshots:

Thunderbird:

[image]

Upload boxes:

[image]

This is really frustrating especially with really good looking KDE Breeze themed apps like KMail and the like.

Comment: Questions on pre-release versions of Ubuntu are off-topic here. Please ask on Launchpad, instead.

Answer (score 2):

The new KDE Theme is called Breeze, but there is no Breeze for GTK (yet?).  The old KDE theme is called Oxygen.

- Close your GTK apps.

Install Oxygen by:

```
sudo apt-get install plasma-theme-oxygen oxygen-molecule  \
gtk2-engines-oxygen  gtk3-engines-oxygen
```

Then go to:

1. System Settings
2. Appearance Section
3. Application Style
4. Gnome Application Style (GTK)
5. GTK Themes section
6. Switch to a different themes for both GTK2 and GTK3, press apply
7. Switch back to oxygen-gtk

Comment: That doesn't work. The packages are broken.

Comment: Worked fine for me.  I'm running it is Virtualbox vm.  Packages change quickly.  Just a sanity check, you ran apt-get update first, right?

Comment: Actually had to reinstall Kubuntu because of a botched `apt-get upgrade`, so I tried switching away from `oxygen-gtk` and back. It works.

Comment: For future reference: Current releases of Kubuntu include uniform Qt and GTK application style. For anything else, see https://github.com/dirruk1/gnome-breeze